# Can't accept connection to http server socket

Tags: java, server, httpserver

I am trying to create a simple server, but am having a problem with trying to accept the connection, specifically the line "connectionSocket = serverSocket.accept();". I also have another class SimpleHttpHandler which handles the connection which is referenced in this code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SimpleHttpServer {

    private String rootDirectory;
    private int port;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket connectionSocket;

    public SimpleHttpServer(String rootDirectory, int port) {
        this.rootDirectory = rootDirectory;
        this.port = port;
    }
    public void start() {
        // Establish the listen socket
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server started");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Inside while");
            // Listen for a TCP connection request
            try {
                connectionSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("Client connected");
                SimpleHttpHandler simpleHandler = new SimpleHttpHandler(rootDirectory);
                simpleHandler.handle(connectionSocket);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleHttpServer server = new SimpleHttpServer(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
        server.start();
    }
}
```

When I accept a new connection, I need to create a handler to handle it.

The Handler class is:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;

import org.omg.CORBA.Request;

public class SimpleHttpHandler {

    private String rootDirectory;
    private StringBuffer readFile;
    private FileInputStream fileInputStream;
    private File file;
    private int b;

    public SimpleHttpHandler(String rootDirectory) {
        this.rootDirectory = rootDirectory;
    }

    public void handle(Socket remote) {

        try {
            // Create in and out streams
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(remote.getInputStream()));
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(remote.getOutputStream());
            // HTTP requests resolved here based on the protocol
            // Read a string line from client
            String line = in.readLine();
            // Send a string to client
            out.println("Not yet implemented");
            // Send an empty line to client
            out.println();
            // Send a byte to client 
            out.write(123);
            // Read a byte from file
            file = this.requestFile(rootDirectory, line);
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            b = fileInputStream.read(); // it returns -1 at end of file
            // Read the file
            BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            readFile = null;
            while(fileReader.readLine() != null) {
                readFile.append(fileReader);
            }
            if(!file.equals(null)) {
                responseMessage(readFile.toString());
            } else {
                errorMessage();
            }
            // Close the remote socket and r/w objects
            in.close();
            out.close();
            remote.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void errorMessage() {
        System.out.println(readFile);
        System.out.println("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("^_^ Internal Server Error!");
        ;
    }

    private void responseMessage(String string) {
        System.out.println("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }

    public File requestFile(String rootDirectory, String path) {
        // Construct a full path by connecting <rootDirectory> and requested relative path
        File file = new File(rootDirectory, path);

        // If it is a directory
        // Then load the file index.html
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            file = new File(file, "index.html");
        }
        // If the file exists, the file object is returned
        // Otherwise null is returned
        if (file.exists()) {
            return file;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are your problems? Do you gen an Exception? Then post the stack trace, please.

Comment: There are no errors, it runs, prints that the server starts and it goes inside the while, but it does not print "Client connected" which indicates that the try/catch in the while loop isn't running.

Comment: What does your client code look like? Or do you connect using a web browser? What does happen at the client side? Any errors there? What server port do you use?

Comment: connect using a web browser and we are testing using 1234